# Why not add "href" attribute to any tag in html5 to make it linkable?

Tags: html

People talk about make the code shorter and in HTML5 you can wrap the whole "article" content into an "a".

So why not to make the article (or any tag) directly linkable just adding "href" attribute (and target if you want)?
in this cases the tag is semantic meaningless.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea was actually part of the never-implemented XHTML2 standard:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-hyperAttributes.html#s_hyperAttributesmodule
- http://xhtml.com/en/future/x-html-5-versus-xhtml-2/#x2-cool-hyperlink

The trouble is that existing browsers (as far as I know) didn't (and, obviously, still don't) support it.

At best, it would have had no effect in existing browsers, meaning authors would have to use the other method anyway until most browsers in use supported the new method. That would make it difficult to test whether the new method actually worked in practice.

At worst, it would cause bugs in existing browsers (I don't know if it actually did).

In contrast, wrapping block-level elements in `<a>` tags did (for the most part) already work. The more backwards-compatible method won out.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this xhtml2!
Maybe with the expansion of chrome they will push this features (is a lonely maybe).
I don't get this. they bother us with "html5 semantic markup" but you are force to use a tag that is clearly an attribute

Comment: I guess it would be neater if you could apply `href` to any element (although I'm not clear on why it would be more semantic). But because it's not backwards-compatible, almost every site would at least have to include `<a>` tags as well, and then in browsers that *did* support `href`-anywhere, you'd have two links. What if they pointed to different URLs? How should the browser render that? It starts getting complicated.

Comment: And BTW.
There is a lot of stuff (not using closing tags, form type attributes, tags as video) that doesn't work at all older browser and has a js fallback (a polyfill).
this in jquery is easy as hell
`$("*:not("a")[href]").each(function(){})`

Comment: Regarding "not using closing tags" - nope, that works fine, and was part of HTML4. You're quite right on the others, but unlike links, those are new pieces of functionality that don't exist in older versions of the language. HTML already had a way to define links, so I suspect creating a slightly different way to define links didn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: I see your point on the polyfill, but duplicating the behaviour of links isn't trivial. Will your script let me CTRL-click on the element to open the link in a new tab? What about if I'm on the Mac and it's CMD-click? What about if I use an obscure browser that allows me to customise the "open link in a new tab" shortcut? Can I mouse over the polyfilled link to see where it does? Do they work on touch devices? Are search engines going to follow links defined like this? Links are pretty much *the* fundamental feature of the web. You dick around with them at your peril.

Comment: Is less semantic in the way that you are adding a meaningless tag as wrapper for a full element (like I said for a full article content).
So you are saying "the whole article links to...", this is pretty much the sense of an attribute. 
It is more semantic not adding meaningless tags. isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, it physically adds the "a" tag on unsupported browsers with **wrapInner**. So the behavior is pretty the same as you add the tag from the beginning 
`$("*[href]:not(a)").each(function(){
 var t = $(this),
  attributes = new Array("href","target","rel","title"),
  wrapper = "<a ";
  for (var i = 0; i >= attr.length; i++) {
   attrib = t.attr(attributes[i]);
   wrapper += attrib? attributes[i]+"='"+attrib+"' " : "";
 
  };
  wrapper += "/>";
  t.wrapInner(wrapper);

})`
This code could be "modernizr relative" and you will double reward the browser for his support to "anyTagLink"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40735/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-pikilon)